# Meteor Accounts-Entry how to prevent an extraSignupField from being stored to the database?

Tags: meteor, minimongo, meteor-accounts

I'm using Meteor's [`account-entry`](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry) package to handle the signin-signup action of my web app. To add a `Confirm Password` field to the sign up form, this is what I've done (in CoffeeScript):

```
AccountsEntry.config
      logo: '/logo.png'
      homeRoute: 'main'
      dashboardRoute: 'main'
      profileRoute: '/profile'
      extraSignUpFields: [
        field: "confirmPassword"
        label: "Confirm Password"
        type: "password"
      ,
        field: "name"
        label: "Full Name"
        placeholder: "Full Name"
        type: "text"
        required: true
      ,
        field: "position"
        label: "Position"
        placeholder: "Developer"
        type: "text"
      ]
```

The problem with this approach is that: it also save the `confirmPassword` field to the database, so that when someone access the database > users collection, they can clearly see every users' password in `confirmPassword` field - which is very bad.

I don't know how to fix this problem yet. I think there may be an attribute which decide whether a specific field should be store in the database or not, but I haven't figured it out yet ! (the `accounts-entry` package [documentation](http://github.differential.io/accounts-entry/) seems not detailed enough to me, I have to say :( )

Can you guys help me with this problem ? Thanks so much in advance !

Comment: You might want to add your voice to this [accounts-entry issue about password confirmation](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/issues/280).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of a password confirmation field is a [known issue with accounts-entry](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/issues/280).

On the other hand, the publish function for the [users collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) should only publish the strictly necessary fields. By default, only `username`, `emails` and `profile` are published to the client.

Anyway, you should not store the confirmPassword in the database to begin with. To do that, hook into [`Accounts.onCreateUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) and delete [that field](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/issues/306) before returning the `user` object:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  delete user.confirmPassword;  // or: delete user.profile.confirmPassword;
  return user;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had my doubt that is accounts-entry issue. But the way you fix it is really really nice !